# Cannot create a catalog in SAS Enterpise Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm trying to save a graphic output into a separate catalog within WORK library using `GOUT=` option:

```
proc gchart data=sashelp.cars gout=car;
    donut type/ name="car";
run;
```

When I do it in Base SAS (9.4), all works, I can see this catalog in Explorer or running `proc catalog catalog=car; contents; run;`

But when I do the same in EG 7.1 catalog is not created and `proc catalog` gives an error `ERROR: Catalog WORK.CAR does not exist`.

Can it be fixed?

Comment: Couple of questions.  Do you mean EG 7.1 (there is no 7.2 as of yet)?  What version of SAS is behind your EG installation, and is it desktop or server - particularly, is this EG on your desktop using Local Server (so the same exact SAS) or is it connecting somewhere else?

Comment: It's definitely not something just EG specific (unless 7.1 adds something else); in my 6.1/SAS 9.4 it works fine.  My guess is something related to your EG pointing to a server, with some setting (maybe your catalog is by default heading somewhere other than WORK?)

Comment: Yes, it's 7.1 actually, edited the question. It's 64-bit Windows 7, desktop installation with local server, nothing unusual.

Comment: I have tried the same code
proc gchart data=sashelp.cars gout=car;
    donut type/ name="car";
run;
proc catalog catalog=car; contents; run;
on EG 7.1 Windows Platform and it worked could you share the log for running the above lines

Comment: please check this https://communities.sas.com/t5/Graphics-Programming/work-gseg-doesn-t-exist-error-when-trying-to-replay-a-gmap-graph/td-p/325348